# How do I export/dump mongodb database?

Tags: mongodb, import

I tried a mongo export like this:

```
./mongodump --db local --collection lecturer
```

and then I tried:

```
./mongodump --db  local --collection posts --out - >  lecturer .csv
```

and I get the same error message: `Syntax Error: syntax error (shell):1`

1. What's wrong with my code?
2. Where is the data stored if export successfully?

Comment: You should accept helpful answers, by the way.

Answer (score 48):

### How to backup and restore databases

Start Mongo, open a new tab in terminal.
First navigate to the folder where you want to save the backup, then
type the following command.

**Backup single database:**

```
mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 --db db_name
```

**Restore single database:**

```
mongorestore --host localhost --port 27017 --db **** dump/db_name
```

(In this case, `****` represents UserDefinedName for the database > mydb dump/db_name > this will import dump db into mydb)

**Backup all databases:**

```
mongodump --host localhost --port 27017
```

**Restore all databases:**

```
mongorestore --host localhost --port 27017  dump
```

Comment: this comment is to help to others, from mongodb 4.4+ you need install mongodb-tools to get mongodump/mongorestore working.

Answer (score 28):

`mongodump` is a command-line utility and it's supposed to be run from the system command prompt, not the mongo javascript shell.

```
./mongodump --db local --collection lecturer
```

if successful, this command will create some files under `dump` directory in the current dir.

Comment: for the mongo clueless like me who came here, replace `local` with the name of the DB you want to export and leave off `--collection` if you want to export the whole db.