# Cannot import mongodb

Tags: mongodb, import

I tried mongo import like this

1. `mongoimport -d test -c foo importfile.json`
2. `mongoimport --host localhost --db local --collection lecturer --type json --file temp.json --headerline --upsert`

and I've got same error message "Syntax Error: missing ; before statement (shell):1"
what's wrong with my code & how to import if my data stored in C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop ?? please help, thank's in advance

Comment: Closely related and probably covered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041614/cant-export-mongodb

Answer (score 90):

mongoimport is intended to run in command prompt and not in the mongo shell. Try exiting out of the shell and running the command.

Comment: I already tried run in command prompt like this below?
[http://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u415/zack_syah/commandprompt.png](http://i1066.photobucket.com/albums/u415/zack_syah/commandprompt.png)
what's wrong and command prompt doesn't recognize syntax? Can you show the step how import with image so I can understand

Comment: "mongoimport is not recognized as a command" means that mongoimport.exe is not in your current path.  The ./ syntax with forward path separators is for unix; Windows uses \.  Assuming c:\mongodb\bin is where you have saved the MongoDB files, you should be able to run from the c:\mongodb\bin\dump directory using either the full path to mongoimport: 
    `c:\mongodb\bin\mongoimport.exe -d test -c foo importfile.bson` 

...or the relative path: 
    `..\mongoimport.exe -d test -c foo importfile.bson`.

Comment: omg. this is also true if you're trying to setup an mlab connection, for anyone else stuck here. geez, thanks!

Comment: how do you pass in creds with this? I'm getting 'unauthorized' when I try to import otherwise

Comment: @user1052073 jesus dude, I sepnt over one hour looking for why i couldnt import the file and I was trying to do it from the shell. I cant believe there was no documentation stating that this command is supposed to be run from CMD. Thanks for the help bro you da real MVP

Answer (score 3):

One solution is:

First, in ***cmd***, change to the directory containing ***mongoexport.exe*** file, then type your command.

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin> .\mongoexport.exe -d foo -c bar -o output.json
```

Answer (score 3):

`mongoimport` is to be run on the terminal and not inside the mongo shell. To run `mongoimport` in terminal, you will need to install the same. On ubuntu, you can do :
`apt-get install mongo-tools`
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was able to figure it out after a brief struggling and googling.
1. Navigate to the bin directory in command prompt
(cd c:..\bin)
2. Run the mongoimport command but you have to specify the full path of your json file.
That solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

try to use CSV is a good.

```
mongoimport -d mydb -c things --type csv --file locations.csv --headerline --upsert
```

You can convert by ms excel.

Answer (score 0):

Open the "Mongo/Server/3.4/bin" folder of mongo db in another command window and try again.It Will work.

Answer (score 0):

Open a new terminal or command prompt within the location of the file you want to import and it should work. It will not work on MongoDB shell

Answer (score 0):

1.) Download the MongoDB Database Tools from MongoDB official Website and Unzip the folder

[image: Mongoimport.exe path]

2.) Copy the json file which contains the data to be imported in the same folder as mongoimport.exe

3.) For Windows open the command prompt and run cd (path to folder with mongoimport.exe)

4.) run command .\mongoimport.exe import_data.json -d database_name -c collection_name --jsonArray

example
[image: import successful]